# How to set the hash for each "page" manually

Tags: java, gwt, errai

With Errai-UI how do you set manually the hash for each pages.

For example:

```
MainPage.java
MainPage.html
```

The hash would be `#MainPage`

How can I change it to `#!MainPage` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the hash with the `path` attribute of the `@Page` annotation. In answer to your specific question, do this:

```
@Templated
@Page(path="!MainPage")
public class MainPage extends Composite {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Although, since the `#!` technique is an official thing for web crawlers and so on, it would be reasonable to request an Errai feature to support this. Some sort of global configuration flag like `org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.USE_HASHBANG=true`. Come discuss on our IRC channel or our errai-dev mailing list!

Comment: You mean file a JIRA issue?

Comment: Our IRC channel is [#errai on Freenode](irc://irc.freenode.net/#errai) and our mailing lists are listed [on our community page](http://www.jboss.org/errai/Community/MailingLists). You are always welcome to just file a JIRA, but this request could probably benefit from a bit of discussion.